# Django display additional info for items in a list

Tags: django, templates

I've a problem and i don't know the *right* way to solve it.

Basically,i've a mode, called Task:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    #mto1: many task made of one template
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template)
    STATUS_CHOISE = (('PR', 'In process'), ('ST', 'Stopped'), ('FN', 'Finished'), ('DL', 'Deleted'),)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOISE, default='ST')
    responses_required = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_deadline = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

which can have several answers

```
class Response(models.Model):
    #mto1: many Responses generated for one task
    task = models.ForeignKey(Template)
    STATUS_CHOISE = (('PR', 'Process'), ('FN', 'Finished'))
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOISE, default='ST')
    date_finished= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    ip_address=models.IPAddressField()
```

now, i would like to display all the task of one user (which comes from the template model, and this is done) with additional information about the answers, which are
- number of answer give (so which status is = FN)
- number of total answer (status FN or PR)
- and maybe some extra info.

i did this

```
@login_required
def TemplateList(request):
    task_list = Task.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render_to_response('task_list.html',{'task_list':task_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but this just display the data present in the model, what about the value i've to compute?

so far i did it with CustomTag, but it doesn't seem a clean solution. i would rather do the logic in the view and then use the template just for display results.
But: how can i add this value to each item of the Task List?

do i have to do like in this:  [Passing additional data to a template in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129906/passing-additional-data-to-a-template-in-django) so create the objects from scratch (which requires me some logic in the template as well since i've to match the value in the list with the objects i crate)? or is there any better solution?

i tried generic view ,like  list_detail.object_list
in this way

```
def TaskListDetail(request):
return list_detail.object_list(
    request,
    queryset = Task.objects.filter(user=request.user),
    template_name = 'task_list.html',
    template_object_name = 'task_list',

)
```

but first, it does not show anything (while the other view shows data), second i don't know how to add extra data in a way that they are matched with the item of the list.

any suggestion?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483424/newbie-django-adding-calculated-results-to-queryset-before-passing-to-templat

Comment: seems good but this does not allow me to pass args. so if i want to compute smt like status = 'PR' and another like status = 'ST' i've to make 2 property functions.

Comment: another thing. when do i've to add the @property annotation and why i dont?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method to your model.

```
class Task(models.Model):
   #mto1: many task made of one template
   template = models.ForeignKey(Template)
   STATUS_CHOISE = (('PR', 'In process'), ('ST', 'Stopped'), ('FN', 'Finished'), ('DL', 'Deleted'),)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOISE, default='ST')
   responses_required = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   date_deadline = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
   date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

   def do_some_calculation(self):
       #make funny things
       return "foo"
```

In your template, you can access this with:

```
{% for taks in task_list %}
   {{ task.do_some_calculation }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: ok, this is pretty much what Ngure replied. 
One question, when should i use @property and when not?